# Why does 5082 SQL Error happen? "Cannot change the versioning state on database ..."

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Can't find any info on the net about this error. I have the following script:

```
USE [master]
GO

IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM sys.databases WHERE name='WebPlatform')
BEGIN
    CREATE DATABASE  [WebPlatform]

    ALTER DATABASE [WebPlatform] SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL = 100

    IF (1 = FULLTEXTSERVICEPROPERTY('IsFullTextInstalled'))
    BEGIN
        EXEC [WebPlatform].[dbo].[sp_fulltext_database] @action = 'enable'
    END

    ALTER DATABASE [WebPlatform] SET ANSI_NULL_DEFAULT OFF,
    ANSI_NULLS OFF,
    ANSI_PADDING OFF,
    ANSI_WARNINGS OFF,
    ARITHABORT OFF,
    AUTO_CLOSE OFF,
    AUTO_CREATE_STATISTICS ON ,
    AUTO_SHRINK OFF ,
    AUTO_UPDATE_STATISTICS ON ,
    CURSOR_CLOSE_ON_COMMIT OFF ,
    CURSOR_DEFAULT  GLOBAL ,
    CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL OFF ,
    NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT OFF ,
    QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF ,
    RECURSIVE_TRIGGERS OFF ,
    ENABLE_BROKER ,
    AUTO_UPDATE_STATISTICS_ASYNC OFF ,
    DATE_CORRELATION_OPTIMIZATION OFF ,
    TRUSTWORTHY OFF ,
    ALLOW_SNAPSHOT_ISOLATION OFF ,
    PARAMETERIZATION SIMPLE ,
    READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT OFF ,
    HONOR_BROKER_PRIORITY OFF ,
    READ_WRITE ,
    RECOVERY FULL ,
    MULTI_USER ,
    PAGE_VERIFY CHECKSUM  ,
    DB_CHAINING OFF 

END
```

When I run it in SQL Server Management Studio I get an exception

```
Msg 5082, Level 16, State 1, Line 13
Cannot change the versioning state on database "WebPlatform" together with another database state.
Msg 5069, Level 16, State 1, Line 13
ALTER DATABASE statement failed.
```

What is wrong here? And what is versioning state? The problem is obviously in the second ALERT statement. This script was originally generated by SQL Management Server (original script was working, I just have got rid of 'GO's separating the lines changing the settings) and I wonder if I need all those lines at all? Will it hurt if I delete them?

Comment: Apparently deleting GO lines hurted - you got error. GO lines are not commands, sent to SQL server - they separate batches, sent to SQL server. Some SQL commands need to be in different batches, like your error message almost explicitly states.

Comment: Yes, I see now I must keep 'GO's. But I actually asked about the settings lines like ANSI_NULL_DEFAULT OFF - do I have to keep these. They are auto-generated and do they really make big difference? I deleted this second ALTER DATABASE statement at all and everything seems working ok. What risks I take if I omit them in a production scenario?

Comment: Versioning state is compatibility level - you apparently can't change it inside same batch as other settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `GO`s are an indication for SSMS to send the commands to SQL Server in separate batches. What this means is that SSMS sends each segment between tow `GO` lines as a separate batch.

There are some commands that must be the first in a batch, speacially those related with configuration changes, and DDL (Data Definition Language, i.e. sentences that create, delete, or alter some object in the database).

So you know now the reason for your error. You must leave the `GO`s where they're because they are important.

For more information look here: [Batches](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175502(v=sql.105).aspx), specially in the Rules for using batches section.

Answer (score 0):

Multiple lines in ALTER DATABASE SET... is legal syntax.  https://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/multiple-alter-database-set-options

The problem here is SQL server does not allow the setting of both ALLOW_SNAPSHOT_ISOLATION and READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT in the same ALTER TABLE statement, as there are combinations of these settings that could be in conflict. In the MS documentation they show these as separate ALTER DATABASE commands, run serially:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/snapshot-isolation-in-sql-server